# Multi selection of shapes, and un-select specific shapes based on criteria in PowerPoint slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to select and group all the objects (Shapes) which is available in slide 1.

I want to exclude the title and table from the selection of the shapes.
I also want to exclude the shape which contains the text " Source".

I am getting the error at "Unselect".

```vb
Sub Selectunselect()

Dim Shp As Shape
Dim curSlide As Long

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.SelectAll

For Each Shp In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    If Shp.HasTable Then
        Shp.Unselect
    End If
Next Shp


    If Shp.HasTitle Then
        Shp.Unselect
    End If
Next Shp


    If Shp.TextFrame.TextRange = "Source" Then
        Shp.Unselect
    End If
Next Shp


    If Shp.TextFrame.HasText And Shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Source*" Then
        Shp.Unselect
    End If
Next Shp

End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your error is probably caused by this line:

```
Shp.TextFrame.TextRange = "Source"
```

Which should be:

```
Shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Source"
```

But in general the problem with your approach is that it's better to just only select the shapes you want, rather than selecting all shapes and trying to deselect them. This should work a little better:

```
Public Sub SelectAllShapes()


            Dim shapeCollection() As Variant
            Dim shpCounter As Long
            Dim oShp As Shape
            Dim currentSlide As Slide

            Set currentSlide = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

            shpCounter = 0
            ReDim shapeCollection(shpCounter)

            For Each oShp In currentSlide.Shapes

            If oShp.Type <> msoPlaceholder And IsItSource(oShp) = False Then
                ReDim Preserve shapeCollection(shpCounter)
                shapeCollection(shpCounter) = oShp.Name
                shpCounter = shpCounter + 1
            End If

            Next

            currentSlide.Shapes.Range(shapeCollection).Select


End Sub


Public Function IsItSource(oShp As Shape) As Boolean

    If oShp.HasTextFrame = False Then
        IsItSource = False
    ElseIf oShp.TextFrame.HasText = False Then
        IsItSource = False
    Else
        If oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.text = "Source" Then
            IsItSource = True
        Else
            IsItSource = False
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

As a shortcut I didn't write a separate function to check for titles or tables (the attached function only checks for placeholders and the text "Source"), but you could easily modify the test function to get at what you want to exclude.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. It is almost working fine. It is really helpful.

Comment: If you end up using this on an existing presentation that already has a variety of sources then you might need to check if the text box contains "source" with an in string function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function